# opendatasource and datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, datetime2

I'm using this trick to load Access data into a temporary table without having to specify all the columns (SQL Server 2008).

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                             'Data Source="d:\Data.MDB"' )...TableName
```

This works fine for the most part except it converts an Access date to a datetime field and not datetime2 which makes this not work dates before 1753.

Is there any trick to force the use of datetime2 *without* having to specify all the columns manually?

Comment: Do you have any dates before 1753, if so why, if not does it really matter?

Comment: Yes some pre 1753 dates are causing trouble and I can't fix the source.  Just bad user input, so happy to adjust the dates.  Unfortunately OPENDATASOURCE converts to datetime regardless of the query and then dies because of it.

Comment: You could try exporting your Access table to a text file, and then use the **Bulk Insert** routine on SQL Server to load the data.